# Specifying the position of an element (e.g. line) in draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net, formatting

I'm wondering if it's posssible to specify the exact position of a line in draw.io. It seems that the only way to do that is the reduce the size of the grid.

Answer (score 0):

There is a position in Arrange tab when an element is selected. Does this help?

Regards,

[image]

Comment: Hello @Marija, thank you for your reply. I'm looking for a way to specify the position in terms of mm, not points

Comment: You are right @GennaroArguzzi I added this to our GitHub so you could track the progress and comment: https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/issues/1915

Comment: thank you very much @Marija